# BLE Connection time much higher on iPhone 11 running iOS 14.4 as compared to iPhone 6 running iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to make a BLE connection from iOS devices with a xGM210P dev board acting as a peripheral .I am able to make successful BLE connection with my iOS source code but there is a huge connection time differences in iPhone 6 and iPhone 11 .

iPhone 6 has BLE 4.0 and iPhone 11 has BLE 5.0 inspite of the fact that iphone 11 has BLE 5.0 which is much faster than BLE 4.0 but its connection time is high as compared to iphone 6 .

For making a BLE connection I am using a connectPeripheral method of CoreBluetooth framework.
So the connection timings are as follows:

1. iPhone 6 running iOS 12.4 takes a total time of ~168ms for making a successful connection.
2. iPhone 11 running iOS 14.4 takes a total time of ~560ms for making a successful connection.

Above timings are measured from the event of initiating a connectPeripheral request till I get a callback in didConnectPeripheral delegate method and these timings are very high in iPhone 11 as compared to iPhone 6 .

Below is the code snippet which I am using.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
self.central = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}
```

Firstly I have initialised the centralManager than checking for the Bluetooth state, if its poweredOn than started with the scanning.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(nonnull CBCentralManager *)central {
switch (central.state) {
    case CBManagerStateUnknown:
        printf("Unknown");
        break;
    case CBManagerStatePoweredOn:{

        CBUUID *readerPeripheral = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"FEE2457F-5AB5-FD8C-F24A-0E3FF4A72566"];
        NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:readerPeripheral];
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:arr options:nil];
        break;
    }}
```

Then I get a discovered devboard peripheral in didDiscoveredPeripheral delegate method below.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI{

if (peripheral.name.length > 0 && [peripheral.name isEqualToString:@"DC0998R21"]) {
    NSLog(@"advertisementData = %@",advertisementData);
    NSLog(@"%@",advertisementData);
    
    NSString * strkCBAdvDataLocalName =        [advertisementData valueForKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"];
    NSData   *datakCBAdvDataManufacturerData = [advertisementData valueForKey:@"kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"];
    [central stopScan];
    NSLog(@"Connect CALLED");
    self.central = central;
    self.scannedPeripheral = peripheral;
    self.scannedPeripheral.delegate = self;
    
    self.dateConnectionStarted = [NSDate date];
    [self.central connectPeripheral:self.scannedPeripheral options:nil];
    
}}
```

Then I get a callback in delegate method didConnectPeripheral below.

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{
NSDate *dateWiteSucessfull = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval diff = [dateWiteSucessfull timeIntervalSinceDate:self.dateConnectionStarted];
NSLog(@"TimeTakeninDIDCONNECT=%f",diff);

//THIS diff is ~560ms in iPhone 11 and ~168ms in iPhone 6     

CBUUID *UUIDService = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:serviceUUID];
[self.scannedPeripheral discoverServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:UUIDService]];
```

}

So basically I am calculating the total time taken from initiating the connection request using connectPeripheral method till I get a callback in didConnectPeripheral method of successful connection happened.

I am not able to understand reason for huge connection time difference between 2 iPhones . I have also gone through this stackoverflow link but no success - [Bluetooth Low Energy Lag / Latency on OS X 10.11 El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197335/bluetooth-low-energy-lag-latency-on-os-x-10-11-el-capitan/37124878#37124878)

I am also reading about the effects of connection parameters like Min and Max Connection interval, slave Latency and tried changing the connection parameters at peripheral's end but still didn't receive any success for reducing the connection timings on iPhone 11.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add any relevant code as a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: @koen Added the code snippet.

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of that dispatch_async in didDiscoverPeripheral. You definitely shouldn't be putting that call onto a global queue. You're forcing CBCentralManager to switch contexts at least twice here. "PRIORITY_HIGH" isn't going to help you connect any faster; at best it won't hurt and it could actually hurt a lot. (And it's making some of this code undefined behavior.) I don't think this is the ultimate cause, but "close to half a second" happens to be just about the delay you get when you dispatch UI events on the wrong queue.

Comment: My bigger suspicion is that you're board's timings don't match Apple's recommendations: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1931/_index.html  (I'd just get rid of the dispatch_async first because it's wrong and super easy to fix.)

Comment: After looking at the doc above, you may want to dig deeper into chapter 36 (Bluetooth Low Energy) of the Accessory Design Guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf Small deviations from the recommendations can lead to very large differences in performance, and the impact is very device dependent (particularly since you're likely having trouble with Packet Length Extension given the devices you're testing with).

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier , I tried removing the dispatch queue but the timings still remains the same, earlier I wasn't using any dispatch queues but in order to fix these high timings I added the queue. But with or without the dispatch queues I am getting the same connection timings on iPhone 11. Also many thanks for pointing to Accessory Design Guidelines.